# minipage environment with bottom-aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I would like to make my figures with bottom-aligned, but the arrows are still in the center. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{dicore1.eps}
\end{minipage}
$\rightarrow$
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{dicore2.eps}
\end{minipage}
$\rightarrow$
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{dicore3.eps}
\end{minipage}
$\rightarrow$
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
 \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{dicore4.eps}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A series of retractions.}
\label{fig:Retr}
\end{figure}
```

It strangely looked like this:
[image]

If I make all of them to be \begin{minipage}[b], then they are indeed bottom-aligned, but the arrows are also bottom aligned.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Another option is to change the definition of the last `minipage` to

```
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.2\textwidth}
```

The first optional argument, `t`, defines the 'anchor' of the `minipage`, so here the top is placed on the baseline. The last optional argument, `b`,  defines where in the `minipage` the content should be placed, here it is placed at the bottom.

The second optional argument, which I left empty, defines the height of the `minipage`. I'm not exactly sure what happens when it is left empty, I assumed it would use the natural height, but someone else would have to verify that.

Comment: To align all images to the bottom you can put `[b][][b]`.

Answer (score 4):

I've stripped your use of `minipage`s to isolate a rudimentary (yet effective) way of dealing with the problem of alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}% Largest image
  \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height}{$\rightarrow$}
  \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height}{$\rightarrow$}
  \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height}{$\rightarrow$}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{A series of retractions.}
  \label{fig:Retr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In your instance, you would only need to raise the arrows using `\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height}{$\rightarrow$}`, although I've done it for the last disproportionate image as well.

The idea is to store in a box the largest of the objects. I did so in `\box1`. Then, subsequent stuff aligned with the baseline is raise by `\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height` (or 50% of the height of the largest object minus 50% of their own height), centering them vertically.

---

Another option is to use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  $\rightarrow$
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  $\rightarrow$
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  $\rightarrow$
  \includegraphics[valign=t,width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A series of retractions.}
  \label{fig:Retr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `export` option ports the keys from `adjustbox` to that of [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) so you can `valign` your images. Note that the `valign` option sets the vertical *anchor* to which other content aligns. So, as you can see, I've set `valign=t` for the last image, meaning the `t`op of that image will align with the anchors of the other components in the horizontal list - `c`enter.

Comment: sorry, seems I did not get it!

Comment: I changed all [c] to [b] and replace $\rightarrow$ to\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\height}{$\rightarrow$}, but it does not work!

Comment: @Ginger: Did you store the largest image in `\box1` like I did with `\setbox`? Also, you should try it *without* the `minipage`s like I did - the width specification of `\includegraphics` should be sufficient.