# How do I format images that are of different sizes?

Tags: graphics, minipage

I am writing a report for class and I cannot figure out how to format multiple images (specifically 4 images) in a nicer way. Can I get some help? Here is my code:

```
        \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tables/B/5.png}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{\fill}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textwidth]{tables/B/6.png}
        \end{minipage}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tables/B/7.png}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{\fill}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textwidth{tables/B/8.png}
        \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
```

But this outputs the following nasty page:

[image]

Comment: Instead of importing pictures of tables, have you considered using [`pgfplotstable`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in my comment, I wouldn't recommend include pictures of tables.  I understand that creating large tables with the `tabular` environment can be somewhat tedious, but if you are tabulating data files, there is [`pgfplotstable`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) that can be immensely helpful (it is distributed with [PGFplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)).

Here's a small example of how it can be used:

```
\documentclass[border=5,export]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
   1.   0.                  0.
   2.   1.3862943611198906  0.34657359027997264
   3.   3.295836866004329   0.1831020481113516
   4.   5.545177444479562   0.057762265046662105
   5.   8.047189562170502   0.013411982603617503
   6.  10.75055681536833    0.0024885548183722988
   7.  13.621371043387192   0.0003860932835427209
   8.  16.635532333438686   0.000051573450934519735
   9.  19.775021196025975   6.054961908444168e-6
  10.  23.02585092994046    6.345307244802815e-7
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/0/.style={
      column name=\(n\),
    },
    columns/1/.style={
      column name=\(x_{n}\),
      fixed, zerofill,
      precision=3,
    },
    columns/2/.style={
      column name=\(\Delta x_{n}\),
      sci, zerofill,
      precision=4,
    },
    every head row/.style={
      before row=\toprule,
      after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
      after row=\bottomrule,
    },
  ]{data.dat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: using PGFplotstable]

If you still wish to include the tables as pictures, then I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132080/26980) which is very similar to yours.  Assuming that you are only using `graphicx` and other packages aren't modifying the other environments, then here is how you can fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with the output being:

[image: fixing the alignment]