# How do you move this asymptote figure to the right?

Tags: asymptote

I'm quite new to LaTeX and I need some help moving this triangle that I've drawn with asymptote to the right, if it's possible. Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Center}

A triangle has many centers, and in this lesson, we will mainly focus on three of them: \underline{centroid}, \underline{incenter}, and \underline{circumcenter}.

\textbf{Centroid}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} 

\begin{flushleft}
A centroid is the intersection of the three medians \linebreak of a triangle, which is usually denoted by $G$.
\end{flushleft}

\begin{asy}
pair A, B, C, D, E, F;
A = (80,80);
B = (0,0);
C = (120,0);
D = (60,0);
E = (100,40);
F = (40,40);
draw((0,0)--(80,80)--(120,0)--cycle);
draw((0,0)--(100,40));
draw((80,80)--(60,0));
draw((120,0)--(40,40));
label("$A$", A, N);
label("$C$", C, SE);
label("$B$", B, SW);
label("$D$", D, S);
label("$E$", E, NE);
label("$F$", F, NW);
\end{asy}


\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

That gives me this:[image]

I want to move the triangle to the highlighted place, if that's possible...

Sorry that I'm very new and don't know quite a lot of stuff. Please be patient with me if I have some questions and *thank you for all your help in advance*!!!

PS I've also seen some people say to use "float"? But I don't really know how to use it...

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would be helpful if you'd extend your example code to begin with `\documentclass` and make it compilable, so potential helpers don't have to do any guessing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton sorry I edited the post to add that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @DandelionDreams Barbara asked to tell you: your question is related to this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378548, so you might find some useful advice about minipages there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\section{Center}
A triangle has many centers, and in this lesson, we will mainly focus on three of them: \underline{centroid}, \underline{incenter}, and \underline{circumcenter}.

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} 
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Centroid}

A centroid is the intersection of the three medians \linebreak of a triangle, which is usually denoted by $G$.
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}% no blank line after
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} 
\begin{flushright}
\begin{asy}
    pair A, B, C, D, E, F;
    A = (80,80);
    B = (0,0);
    C = (120,0);
    D = (60,0);
    E = (100,40);
    F = (40,40);
    draw((0,0)--(80,80)--(120,0)--cycle);
    draw((0,0)--(100,40));
    draw((80,80)--(60,0));
    draw((120,0)--(40,40));
    label("$A$", A, N);
    label("$C$", C, SE);
    label("$B$", B, SW);
    label("$D$", D, S);
    label("$E$", E, NE);
    label("$F$", F, NW);
    \end{asy}
\end{flushright}    
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Note: This is compiled with F1 in TexMaker

[image]