# How to align minipages really to the top?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I have this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{green}{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
  left content
\end{minipage}
}
\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{green}{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.jpg}
  \newline
  right content
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

This renders to this:

[image]

As you can see, it does not matter, what property do I set to `\begin{minipage}`, the minipages are not rendered to the top.

I want *both* minipages to render to the top of the page. How can I do that?

Comment: Check out the answers the answer to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378548/231952

Comment: they are aligned on the baselines of the top row of each, the baseline of left content and teh baseline of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\adjustbox{minipage=10cm,valign=t,cfbox=red,bgcolor=green}{%
  left content
}%
\adjustbox{minipage=5cm,valign=t,cfbox=red,bgcolor=green}{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
  \newline
  right content
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, it is extreme! I really can not wonder on your rep. :-) Btw, do the seemingly unneeded `%`s in your code have some function? I try it and then accept comes likely soon.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica: See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)