# `NiceTabular` vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, nicematrix

I'm trying to split a large table (I use `NiceTabular` environment from `nicematrix` package) into two parts and arrange them side by side. At the same time, I want the tables to be vertically aligned not in the center, but the first part up and the second down. For example, this is how I want the tables to look like:

```
If the first half       If the right half
is higher in height:    is higher in height:
    a a                     a a  a a
    a a  a a                a a  a a
    a a  a a                     a a
```

To achieve this goal, I tried adding the argument `[t]` to the first table, and `[b]` to the right one. However, the result surprised me: the first half turned out to be lower than the right one. Example:

```
     a a
a a  a a
a a
a a
```

How can to fix this problem and achieve the desired alignment?

I tried various solutions from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378548/171124) question, but either there was no effect, or the file stopped compiling.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{cc}
        a & a \\
        a & a \\
        a & a
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \quad
    \begin{NiceTabular}[b]{cc}
        a & a \\
        a & a
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps in this question it is possible to replace nicetabular with tabular, but I used `NiceTabular` and I assume that solutions working with `tabular` may not work with `NiceTabular`.

Comment: `b` means that the bottom (that is, the last row of the tabular) is at the same level as the text surrounding the tabular, while `t` means that the top (the first row of the tabular) is at the same level. Hence the vertical alignment that you get. You can maybe better understand this by typing an `a` right before the two instances of `\begin{NiceTabular}`.

Comment: you want both `[b]`  in this case or both `[t]` if the second one is larger

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jasper Habicht's comment, I found a solution: it is necessary to make `[b]` or `[t]` for both tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}[b]{cc}
%                      ^^^
        a & a \\ a & a \\ a & a
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \quad
    \begin{NiceTabular}[b]{cc}
%                      ^^^
        a & a \\ a & a
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

for

```
a a
a a  a a
a a  a a
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{cc}
%                      ^^^
        a & a \\ a & a \\ a & a
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \quad
    \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{cc}
%                      ^^^
        a & a \\ a & a
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

for

```
a a  a a
a a  a a
     a a
```

Comment: UPD: also thanks to David Carlisle