# vertically aligning panels of varying width with minipage

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to top-align figure panels using `minipage`. It works fine if both minipages have the same width, but if they don't, it doesn't work: the figure panel in the smaller minipage appears below its desired position. I don't understand what is the problem, since minipage width should not matter. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}  
    \centerline {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}\vfill
    \centerline {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.png}}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}    
    \centerline {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c.png}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Among other things, I tried

```
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.3\textwidth}
```

as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132240/293937), as well as `\strut` and `\raisebox` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378553/293937), with no luck so far.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: `\centerline {  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}` will force the image off centre as it has a space to the left

Comment: [t] aligns the first baseline, which is at the bottom of the image.  You can use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to add `[valign=T]` to `\includegraphics`.  or jsut use `\raisebox{-\height}{...}`/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comment. I try to be mindful about avoiding extra spaces, but they still appear every now and then. For example, auto-indent might add spaces. What would you recommend as a workflow for avoiding spurious spaces while maintaining source files' readability? (sorry for asking in a comment)

Comment: spaces at the beginning of a line are not a problem (tex strips them) so indentation isn't a problem, just don't add spaces.`\fbox{ a }` is not the same as `\fbox{a}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `\includegraphics` extend upward from the "top-aligned" baseline.  Differing image sizes will leave them misaligned at top.

Here, I use the `\belowbaseline` macro from `stackengine` package to achieve top alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \belowbaseline[0pt]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}  
    \centerline {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}\vfill
    \centerline {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.png}}
  \end{minipage}}\hfill
  \belowbaseline[0pt]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}    
    \centerline {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c.png}}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]