# How to align tables side by side starting from the same level?

Tags: tables

I looked at the code from vanden [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} &

    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        3 & 4 \\
        g & e \\
        f & e \\
        f & e \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How to do that tables start in the same level in the same hight of the page? And how to add caption to both tables? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `subcaption` package

Comment: Replace `\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}` by `\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{.48\linewidth}` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132240/121799

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Common caption}
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\textwidth} % Look at option [t]
    \centering
        \caption{A caption}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1 & 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \caption{Another caption}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            3 & 4 \\
            g & e \\
            f & e \\
            f & e
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`.5\textwidth` is a bit too wide I think